# How do I create an aspect ratio overlay on camera plugin in Flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, instagram

I'm trying to create an overlay over the CameraPreview like how Instagram does it

[image: Preview]

How can I do this with Flutter's camera plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the preview and add an overlay. For camera you can use this package
https://pub.dev/packages/camera

Create a controller

```
controller = CameraController(_cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max);
```

Manage the controller

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  final CameraController? cameraController = controller;

  // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
  if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
    return;
  }

  if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
    cameraController.dispose();
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    onNewCameraSelected(cameraController.description);
  }
}
```

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned.fill(
      child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 4/3,
          child: CameraPreview(controller)),
    ),
    Positioned.fill(
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: 0.3,
        child: Image.network(
          'urlfor the overlay image here',
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    ),
   Positioned(
    bottom : 0,
    child: Container(), //other widgets like capture etc here
   )
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mate. But I want the camera to fill the entire screen, and have that overlay in the center rather than having the camera preview only on that overlay. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Oh so the dark section will be in the center and other parts will be displayed in the photo?

Comment: Yeah something like that. If you see the image that I have included in the question, you can see that the camera fills the entire screen. The center part (overlay) is highlighted, while the top and bottom part is darkened yet still show the camera preview. I hope this makes sense

Comment: I've been trying to do this for a week, but I've got no luck. Any help would be of great help

Comment: The code that i have added in the answer will work. You just have to create an image like the overlay. Here by overlay i mean the dark area with a hollow center

Comment: Just remove the aspect ratio widget and it should be full preview. And on capture change aspect ratio -> capture -> change aspect ratio again

Comment: but I want that aspect ratio overlay on the center even though the camera preview is full screen